# Why did adding a month only add 31 days and not a month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Very strange error indeed. I have an item that clones itself every month, setting the next object to have a `scheduled_on` date, `+ 1.months` in the future.

But then this happened :

```
Sun, 01 Apr 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Tue, 01 May 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Fri, 01 Jun 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Sun, 01 Jul 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Fri, 31 Aug 2012 17:00:00 PDT -07:00 # <--- What in the..
```

The code :

```
def clone_object
  objects = []

  Time.zone = account.timezone
  Chronic.time_class = Time.zone

  now = last_scheduled_on.to_time # <- this would have been Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00

  new_date = now + 1.months

  new_schedule = Time.zone.parse new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d' + ' ' + original_scheduled_on.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

  objects << clone!(:scheduled_on => new_schedule, :recurring_job_id => id)

end
```

That is a very truncated version of the actual code. But it includes all the parts that I are reasonably affecting this issue.

So the question is.. how could that error could have possibly occurred?

**Update**

I'm pretty sure this is timezone related.

Here's the Dates in UTC:

```
In UTC :

Sun, 01 Apr 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
Tue, 01 May 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
Fri, 01 Jun 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
Sun, 01 Jul 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
Wed, 01 Aug 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
Sat, 01 Sep 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
Sun, 30 Sep 2012 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Here they are converted to Pacific :

```
In Pacific

Sun, 01 Apr 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Tue, 01 May 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Fri, 01 Jun 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Sun, 01 Jul 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
Fri, 31 Aug 2012 17:00:00 PDT -07:00
Sun, 30 Sep 2012 16:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

I also noted that the code I put here in not accurate to my server. The server has the Time.zone set to the last job and **not the account's timezone**. This means ( or at least I think it means ), that the timezone is then floating and dynamic. But that bothers me also because Daylight savings time in California does not switch over until November, not September.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create new_scheduled_on at all. Typo? Does your cut down version have the same invalid behaviour?

Comment: My apologies Frederick. It was a typo. I have built roughly 700 lines of Test Unit code against this and it all passes with flying colors including testing this locally by using the app. But for some reason when the workers run this, after a few months pass, these slips are noted.

Comment: Is the change from 4pm to 5pm expected?

Comment: The one hour difference is unexpected. Updating with some new findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because when you add two DateTime's, the DateTime object will add by number of days and discredit timezones.

When you add two Time objects together, they will add by the hour, and include any timezone differences.

The hour difference occurred specifically because two DateTime's were added together that transgressed over a Timezone change. The time then is saved to the database in UTC as the same number despite the fact that when they are later parsed in their respective timezone's, they will be offset by one hour.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried .next_month ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-months_since

Comment: This is equivalent to `+ 1.months`, no?

Answer (score -1):

Time calculations are always problematic. 1.month might be 30 days, 31 days, 28 days, or anything in between. It depends on the month being added, what you're adding to it, and so on. So errors like this are unfortunately and annoyingly common-place when doing date arithmetic.

To correct this code, I would always ensure it selects the beginning of the month for the month you're in, like so:

```
new_date = (now + 1.months).beginning_of_month
```

That will always be the 1st of the month.

Comment: Not if, as Trip indicates, 01 Aug + `1.month` is 31 Aug.

Comment: if `new_date = (now + 1.months)` returns the 31st of that month then adding the method `beginning_of_month` would take it to the beginning of the wrong month. No?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry, I didn't read the question closely enough. Try this instead: ```(now + 1.months).beginning_of_month.next_month```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. Man, reading comprehension failure. :(

Comment: Okay okay. Try this: `now.beginning_of_month.next_month`.